# Get the min speed with particular name and mac in the stop_distance range of 40 m

Tags: mysql

I am trying to the get `min speed` with particular `stop_name` and `mac`. This min speed should be the one with stop_distance range of 40 m.

**Screenshot I wan to get the green one and not the red one**
[image]

**mysql query: Here I am getting different result with different stop_name**

```
SELECT mac, stop_name, stop_distance, speed from behaviour
where speed = (SELECT MIN(speed) from behaviour where stop_distance < 40
 and mac = '10:A5:D0:06:C6:E9' and stop_name = 'Sandstraße' )  LIMIT  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT mac, stop_name, stop_distance, speed 
from behaviour
where stop_distance < 40 and mac = '10:A5:D0:06:C6:E9' and stop_name = 'Sandstraße' 
order by speed
LIMIT  1
```